# testnet addresses on bitcoin

Tags: testnet

I was wondering how  testnet addresses like https://testnet.blockchain.info/address/myaj43o2wt34j31ej5pmP6htCHFafAKoeP
are created? 
Also is there a script to create them?

Answer (score 2):

this address is a standard P2PKH testnet address, and can be derived from a typical priv/public keypair, by adding [the testnet prefix](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes). There is a page you can [play with](http://gobittest.appspot.com/Address) - in Step 4 you would change the default prefix "00" to "6F", and get a corresponding address. The composition of such an address and further details are again in [the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses) .